# Is there a fast replacement for deprecate `SKPaymentTransaction.transactionReceipt`?

Tags: ios, ios7, in-app-purchase, deprecated

Is there a fast replacement for deprecate SKPaymentTransaction.transactionReceipt?

The full code:

```
// saves a record of the transaction by storing the receipt to disk
- (void)recordTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
    if ([transaction.payment.productIdentifier isEqualToString:[self getProductId:gFullVersion]]) {
        // save the transaction receipt to disk
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:transaction.transactionReceipt forKey:[self getProductId:gFullVersion]];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct answer should be:

```
[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL]]
```

And the full code:

```
// saves a record of the transaction by storing the receipt to disk
- (void)recordTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
    if ([transaction.payment.productIdentifier isEqualToString:[self getProductId:gFullVersion]]) {
        // save the transaction receipt to disk
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL]] forKey:[self getProductId:gFullVersion]];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }
}
```

Comment: @MaciejSwic how do you verify receipt for individual transaction without using the deprecated transactionReceipt property?

Comment: @user1681701 All the receipts are in the bundle, iirc you get an array or dictionary back, loop through it and you will find all IAP receipts in there as well.

Comment: Downvoted, this code snippet is not an exact replacement for retrieving the receipt info associated with a single transaction.

Comment: Downvoted too. Doesn't answer the question at all.